# Hide students in o365 address book - powershell

Tags: powershell

I work for a school and since last week all students also get a o365 account.

- Is it possible that they don't have acces to the adress book so they cannot see the other users /how?
- Is it possible that the teachers can see each other, but the student list is not visible for them? /how

Thanks in advance!
Laurent

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want to achive is GAL-segmentation (GAL = Global Adress List).
This can be done by using Address Book Policies (ABP) in Office365.
See this example from MS Docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/address-books/address-book-policies/address-book-policies